# WCF - EndPoint Not Found Exception

Tags: web-services, web-config, app-config, wcf-endpoint, endpointnotfoundexception

I have been beating my head against this for two days and tried a number of things to try to get this to work to no avail.  I'm trying to get this system to work on my local machine for debugging purposes.  I'm hoping somebody here can see something that I've become blind to, or can offer some sort of advice.

I have two wcf services (actually 4, but more on that later).  One is a SOAP webservice running on IIS.  The webservice is trying to make a call to the other service (the agent).  In the production environment, there are two firewalls between the two services.  They use net.tcp protocol with certificate security to connect.

We use self-signed certificates for development and qa purposes.

I have the client and service certificates installed and have granted the app pool read access to the certificates.

I have verified that Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service, Net.Tcp Listener Adapter, Net.Pipe Listener Adapter are all running.

net.tcp protocal is enabled and net.tcp binding is defined in IIS.

The firewall is off.

Both services connect to an Identity Management service (IMS) which is also a WCF service running on a qa server, not my local machine. The webservice is able to successfully connect to the IMS service.  I'm trying to use the same binding to connect to the agent service.  As far as I can tell the address, binding and contract are all matching between the webservice and the agent, yet I still get the EndPointNotFoundException.  What have I missed?

Here is the system.serviceModel section from the web.config for the webservice:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8102/Acord/201307" behaviorConfiguration="NetTcpCertificatesBehavior" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpCertificatesBinding" contract="AcordContract.IAcordService201307" name="AcordCertificateEndpoint">
    <identity>
      <certificateReference findValue="(value redacted)" isChainIncluded="false" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="NetTcpCertificatesBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="(value redacted)" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
        <serviceCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
        </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpCertificatesBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security>
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="NetTcpMessageCertificatesBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
             transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="100"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="100" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="NetTcpWindowsBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
             transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="65535" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="NetTcpMessageWindowsBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="100" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="100" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"  />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Here is the system.serviceModel section from the app.config for the agent service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics performanceCounters="Default"/>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpWindowsBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" 
             transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
             listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="65535" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="NetTcpCertificatesBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="00:10:00" portSharingEnabled="true">
      <security>
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="NetTcpMessageWindowsBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="100" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="100" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"  />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>      
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="AcordAgent.AcordService" behaviorConfiguration="AcordServiceBehavior">

    <endpoint address="http://qaschedapp:8100/Acord" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="HttpWebGetBehavior" contract="AcordContract.IMeta" name="MetaEndpoint">
      <!--the name of this endpoint above (MetaEndpoint) must stay-->
    </endpoint>
    <!--binding for clients within the firewall calling from C# with WCF -->
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8101/Acord/201307" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpMessageWindowsBinding" name="NetTcpWindowsEndpoint" contract="AcordContract.IAcordService201307">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <!--binding for clients outside the firewall calling from C# with WCF using certs -->
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8102/Acord/201307" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpCertificatesBinding" name="NetTcpCertificatesEndpoint" contract="AcordContract.IAcordService201307">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8102/Acord/mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="NetTcpCertificatesBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="(value redacted)" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"/>
        <serviceCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="None"/>
        </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AcordServiceBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="(value redacted)" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"/>
        <clientCertificate>
          <certificate findValue="(value redacted)" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"/>
        </clientCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Addendum:  I have just run netstat -a and I don't see anything listening on port 8102.  So clearly that is why I'm getting the response I am getting. The question I have now is, why is the agent not listening on 8102?  I have the agent service running in Visual Studio 2015 with break points set.  Do I need to install the service and then attach to the process?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was that there is an appSetting in this application's config file that controls whether the servicehost gets created or not and the setting was set to false.  I can't say why there is such a setting in the config file.  Setting the appSetting to true, however, has simply revealed a whole new problem.  So, on to the next problem.